# Django REST API Generics displaying improperly

Tags: django, rest, api, generics, view

Currently using a REST API and the generic views CreateUpdateDestroy, and my admin display GUI looks like this : [image: admin views: looks so ugly]

All the sources online that I've followed, tutorials etc get a generic view which looks much nicer.

Here is my views.py:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from models import Results
from serializers import ResulutsSerializer

class ResultsList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Results.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ResultsSerializer

class ResultsDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Results.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ResultsSerializer
```

and urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from main import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('results/', views.ResultsList.as_view()),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.ResultsDetails.as_view())
]
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you seeing the errors in your browser window console? a lot of `404`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to collect your app assets:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic 
# You can provide option: --settings=<your-settings-file> if you're using custom settings which is not default in manage.py
```

You will need to configure [staticfiles settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#settings-staticfiles) in your Django settings module if not already configured – e.g. `settings.py`. Please follow documentation at: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

**If you are developing locally:**

You should set `DEBUG=True` in your Django Settings Module (i.e. normally `settings.py`)

Comment: @ice_cream glad that it was helpful. Please accept this as an answer if this answers your question – Thanks.